# Recourse for a 'tree' of the objects studied in Abstract Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am writing a study guide for my Abstract Algebra course this semester, and the first midterm is approaching so I am preparing to share it with my peers. I included an 'extra information' section to show some applications of Abstract Algebra (like the permutations of a Rubik's cube, etc.). One thing I wanted to add was a "tree" of objects that we study in Abstract Algebra as we add more structure to the previous object, starting with a set, then a group, then Abelian Group, then a ring, then commutative ring, then integral domains, then fields, then vector spaces, then an inner product space, etc. etc.. I quickly realized I couldn't just use a "chain" of objects and instead a tree would be much more fitting. I want to make sure this is accurate. Is there any resource available that will help me order these objects correctly?

Comment: Do you want something like these? [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361889/655547](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361889/655547)

Comment: Actually, looking at those more closely, there's a lot of structures people don't care about... I'll look for a better one

Comment: @HallaSurvivor that is exactly what I want, just simplified to a more general description of each object if that makes sense.

Comment: @Ty I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "more general description". Can you go into some more detail, please?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Sure, I mean I would like the tree to include sets, groups, rings, commutative rings, integral domains, fields, vector spaces, etc. Sort of the "big" objects studied in Abstract Algebra. For example, a ring is an Abelian Group with a second binary operation, so I would place the ring as a child of an abelian group, and an abelian group as the child of a group, so on and so forth.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/yYJcmjRVN3eJWP5d7 how is this? There is some extra stuff you might not see in a first Algebra course, but the right half is fairly accessible

Comment: @HallaSurvivor That is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Of course! Should I add it as an answer, or would you prefer to leave the question open for other people to give input?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I would say that resource is more than sufficient, so feel free to leave it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moved from the comments:

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361889/graphically-organizing-the-interrelationships-of-basic-algebraic-structures) is a MSE question where people were discussing a similar question, and below is a graphic from wikipedia that shows everything you might find in a first algebra course (as well as a fair bit more...)

[image: wikipedia image]